# Fundamental group about fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, fiber-bundles, fibration

Let $E\to B$ be a fiber bundle (or more genereal, a fibration), and $B'$ be a section.

1. Is it true that $\pi_1(B')$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(E)$?
2. Is it true that $\pi_1(B)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(B')$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that $B'$ is a retract of $E$. To see this, let $r: E \to B'$ be the composition $E \to B \to B'$, where the last map is the section map. What does this tell us on the level of fundamental groups?

For the second question, note that the restriction of $E \to B$ to $B'$ is a homeomorphism, as it has an inverse.

EDIT: None of this uses the fact that $E \to B$ is a fiber bundle.